# In the Javascript StackTrace timeline is code directly in front of layout the cause?

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, layout, google-chrome-devtools

Trying to understand something about Chrome debugger performance timeline.

It moves left to right as the performance trace is recorded (timewise), and in the call stack (flame chart or whatever it's called) for Javascript, the top calls the items below, so on and so forth moving down.

My question after reading all the debugger docs is, no matter the time the Javascript code takes to execute, (even if 5ms), is the Javascript DIRECTLY in front of the purple 'layout Render Tree' at the top the direct cause of the layout render tree (to the right)? In the same way the top javascript calls the code below, does the code infront call the next action?

Or would it be the code at the bottom (#2)? Or can it be ANY of the javascript code before (#3)?

Thank you.

[image: timeline]

Comment: Basic info: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference

Comment: Thank you. Trust me I have THOROUGHLY reviewed all that as mentioned. I appreciate it still. All it says is "The x-axis represents the recording over time."

Comment: closest I can get is the EVENT LOG tab but that only shows be the order of the selection. Not what causes the updateRenderTree (which is what I am after, and wondering if the code before is the direct cause).